# How to send zip file with bash script?

Tags: bash, email, ssh, amazon-ses

I'm able to send simple files, and I'm able to zip a file inn bash... I'm not sure how to put the two together

for context temporaryDirectory is a folder with all the files I want to send

```
zip attachmentt.zip "${temporaryDirectory}"/*
ATTACHMENT="attachmentt.zip.zip"

# Create message
echo '{"Data":"From:'${MAIL_ACCOUNT}'\nTO:'${recipient}'\nSubject:'${MAIL_SUBJECT}'\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-type: Multipart/Mixed;boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n--NextPart\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\n'${body}'\n\n--NextPart\nContent-Type: attachment/zip;Content-Description:'${ATTACHMENT}';Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='${ATTACHMENT}'\";Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64"}' > message.json

aws ses send-raw-email --raw-message file://message.json
```

This sends the email with an attachment, but it is a blank file...

Comment: Do you know if the email is waiting for the whole file to zip prior to firing off?

Comment: remove the the 2nd `.zip` from ATTA... variable? Good luck.

Comment: You haven't put the attachment contents in the message. See https://gist.github.com/gnuton/6a02225b0cbff6547b78723564aee63c